# Problem when trying to add active class to current element in a <li> and images with transitions

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm trying to make that after click on a list element ( `<ul>` `<li>` ) the corresponding image is displayed. Title A displays Image A, Image B displays Image B, etc.

**The problem:**
What I did was add an active class in the css and js, but this makes all the images visible.

This is what I could get:

```js
var random = $(this).parent().index()
    $(".sidebarx-header-display img").addClass("active");
```

Here is the full js:

```js
$(function(){
  
  // Img display Header Mouse Enter

  const lis = $(".sidebarx-list-item-title")
  lis.on('mouseenter', function() {
    const index = lis.index(this)
    $(".sidebarx-header-display img.show").removeClass("show");
    $(".sidebarx-header-display img").eq(index).addClass("show");
  })

  // Mouse Leave
  lis.on('mouseleave', function() {
    const index = lis.index(this)
    $(".sidebarx-header-display img.show").addClass("show");
    $(".sidebarx-header-display img").eq(index).removeClass("show");
  })
 
  // Slide submenu
  
  $(".sidebarx-list-item-title").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".sidebarx-list-item-submenu").css({"right":"0px"});
    
   // Prolem X_X
    var random = $(this).parent().index()
    $(".sidebarx-header-display img").addClass("active");
   // + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + +
  });

  $(".header-test").click(function(){
    $(".sidebarx-list-item-submenu").css({"right":"-100%"});
    $(".sidebarx-header-display img").removeClass("active");
  });
  
});
```

Css active:

```css
.sidebarx-header-display img.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Here the code online since it is a bit big: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/AlexK90/pen/ExePopK)

Comment: Hi, as you are already getting the `index` so you can try `$(".sidebarx-header-display img").eq(random).addClass("active")`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2goyjets/ : do you want like this?